# I'm trying to add a column from one dataframe to another in Python, but not I'm not succcessful

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have these two dataframes, cd2 and cd3. I want to add the cat_gm column from cd3 to cd2:

```
cd2
    cat      rand  freq     _merge
7    21  0.810730     2  left_only
8    21  0.591324     3  left_only
12   22  0.083941     3  left_only
13   22  0.378123     4  left_only

cd3
    cat  freq  cat_gm      _merge
14   11     2    11.0  right_only
15   12     3    12.0  right_only
16   12     4    12.0  right_only
17   12     5    12.0  right_only
```

In order to obtain my objective, I tried the following code:

```
cd2['cat_gm']=pd.Series(cd3['cat_gm'])

cd2
    cat      rand  freq     _merge  cat_gm
7    21  0.810730     2  left_only     NaN
8    21  0.591324     3  left_only     NaN
12   22  0.083941     3  left_only     NaN
13   22  0.378123     4  left_only     NaN
```

As you can see, all I got was missing values. I want this instead:
    `cd2['cat_gm']=pd.Series(cd3['cat_gm'])`

```
cd2
Out[13]: 
    cat      rand  freq     _merge  cat_gm
7    21  0.810730     2  left_only     11.0
8    21  0.591324     3  left_only     12.0
12   22  0.083941     3  left_only     12.0
13   22  0.378123     4  left_only     12.0
```

Where did I go wrong?

The following code is how I created cd2 and cd3 in the first place:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 a=pd.DataFrame({'cat':[11,12,21,22],'freq':[2,3,4,5]})
 b=pd.DataFrame({'cat':[11,12,21,22],'freq':[3,6,2,3]})

 c=pd.Series.to_frame(np.repeat(a['cat'],a['freq']))
 d=pd.Series.to_frame(np.repeat(b['cat'],b['freq']))

 c['rand']=np.random.uniform(0,1,len(c.index))
 c['freq']=c.groupby('cat').cumcount()
 d['freq']=d.groupby('cat').cumcount()

 c.sort_values(by=['rand'])


 d['cat_gm']=d['cat']

 cd=pd.merge(c,d,on=['cat','freq'],how='outer',indicator=True)

 cd1=cd[cd._merge=='both']
 cd2=cd[pd.isna(cd['cat_gm'])==True]
 cd2=cd2.drop(['cat_gm'],axis=1)

 cd3=cd[pd.isna(cd['rand'])==True]
 cd3=cd3.drop(['rand'],axis=1)
```

Comment: if you assign a series to a column in Pandas, it will assign based on the indices. Because your indices don't match, it uses NaN.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.

    `cat_gm=cd3['cat_gm'].as_matrix()

    cd2['cat_gm']=cat_gm`

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is joining the data on an index but your series doesn't have the same index as the parent data frame. Instead you can feed it a numpy array of the data.

```
cd2['cat_gm'] = cd3['cat_gm'].values
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html),

```
cd2 = cd2.reset_index(drop=True)
cd3 = cd3.reset_index(drop=True)
```

And then use `pd.concat` to copy a column from one data frame to another data frame,

```
new_df =  pd.concat([cd2, cd3[['cat_gm']]], axis=1)
```

Now you get what you need,
`print(new_df)`, the result,

```
    cat     rand    freq    _merge  cat_gm
0   21  0.102928    2   left_only   11.0
1   21  0.803516    3   left_only   12.0
2   22  0.054483    3   left_only   12.0
3   22  0.724568    4   left_only   12.0
```